# Tenant area route with default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

So I have a site that has basically an 'area' per tenant. so it will show up as www.site.com/ and that will go to that groups page using an area.

Thing is I also have a default route for outside the area so you can go to www.site.com/ which will take you to the actual ~/Views/Home/Index page. However if you try to type www.site.com/Home/Index or say the page to create a new group www.site.com/Group/Create it thinks it needs to go to the area which that doesn't exist and gives the 404 resource cannot be found.

Here is the default route in the RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new[] { "TicketSystem.Controllers" }
        );
```

Here is the route config for the area:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Group_default",
            "{group}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "TicketSystem.Areas.Group.Controllers" });
```

so the {group} is whatever group you are currently visiting and then it goes to the regular controller/action for that group. However for the default route it still seems to go to the area route instead no matter what.

I was thinking that there could be a fallback. So when it tries to go to the area and it can't find the correct controller/action it will check the default route next. If it still can't find anything it will give the 404 error resource cannot be found. Though I am not exactly sure how to do this.

So to make www.site.com/ to work and allow www.site.com/Home/Index to work.

Comment: What is the `group` value ? Can it be only one from the areas you have in the app or any random string ?

Comment: @Shyju The group value for the area can be any string as long as it has no spaces. When loading the area it checks to make sure that the group exists in the database. So it could be www.site.com/testgroup or www.site.com/othergroup and those should both go to the actuals group page.

Comment: So you basically have a single area. rite ? When the group is in url, you want that to be handled by the area ?

Comment: Yes, a single area that will contain all access/pages for the group. Any pages that don't require a group will be in the regular controller/views. So www.site.com/group1 will go to the area but www.site.com/home/index will go to the regular Home controller and Index action. Currently it is thinking that the home in www.site.com/home/index is a group based on the routes in my OP.

Comment: I posted an answer which should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, When you try to access `/Home/Index` The route engine does not know by "Home" , you meant the controller name or a groupName!

To solve this, you can create a custom route constraint which checks whether the group value in the request url is a valid controller name in your app. If yes, The request won't be handled by the area route registration definition.

```
public class GroupNameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName,
                       RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //Get all the controller names

        var controllerTypes = (from t in asm.GetExportedTypes()
            where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            select t.Name.Replace("Controller", ""));
        var groupName = values["group"];
        if (groupName != null)
        {
            if (controllerTypes.Any(x => x.Equals(groupName.ToString(),
                                                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Register this constraint when you register your area route.

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Group_default",
            "{group}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { anything = new GroupNameConstraint() }


        );
    }
```

This should work assuming you will never have a groupName same as your controller name (Ex : Home )

Comment: Awesome that works perfect! I can add in a simple check to make sure people can't make a group name same as any controller name, shouldn't be to difficult. First time checking out constraints too, best way I learn is to actually use them and now that I am using one in my own context it all makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: For those doing profiling, you can add

`if (groupName.ToString().Equals("VSEnterpriseHelper.axd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){ return false; }` which will allow the profiling axd file to work properly instead of it thinking it is a group.

Probably an easier way to do this but it lets you know where the issue is actually happening. If you wanted like an asmx file or something.